# connect webots and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, webots

I want to connect cyberrobotics Webots software and MATLAB. 
In Webots I choose "Robotic Contest" and I opened world "nao_matlab" that is exist in webot and when I compile and run this message in console shown:

what's problem?

```
Starting Matlab...
Starting Matlab...
[supervisor_matlab]  
[supervisor_matlab]   To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
[supervisor_matlab]   For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
[supervisor_matlab]  
[nao_matlab]  
[nao_matlab]   To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
[nao_matlab]   For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
[nao_matlab]  
[supervisor_matlab] Error using ==> loadlibrary at 480
[supervisor_matlab] There was an error running the loader mfile.  Use the mfilename option
[supervisor_matlab] to produce a file that you can debug and fix if needed.  Please report
[supervisor_matlab] this error to the MathWorks so we can improve this function.
[supervisor_matlab] 
[supervisor_matlab] 
[supervisor_matlab] Error in ==> launcher at 43
[supervisor_matlab]       loadlibrary Controller allincludes.h ...
[supervisor_matlab] 
[supervisor_matlab] Caused by:
[supervisor_matlab]     Error using ==> feval
[supervisor_matlab]     Error: File: C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\libController_proto.m Line: 364 Column: 9
[supervisor_matlab]     The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
[nao_matlab] Error using ==> loadlibrary at 480
[nao_matlab] There was an error running the loader mfile.  Use the mfilename option
[nao_matlab] to produce a file that you can debug and fix if needed.  Please report
[nao_matlab] this error to the MathWorks so we can improve this function.
[nao_matlab] 
[nao_matlab] 
[nao_matlab] Error in ==> launcher at 43
[nao_matlab]       loadlibrary Controller allincludes.h ...
[nao_matlab] 
[nao_matlab] Caused by:
[nao_matlab]     Error using ==> feval
[nao_matlab]     Error: File: C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\libController_proto.m Line: 364 Column: 9
[nao_matlab]     The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
[nao_matlab] 
[nao_matlab] 
[supervisor_matlab] 
[supervisor_matlab]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a very good guide to integrate matlab with webots could be found here http://www.cyberbotics.com/dvd/common/doc/webots/guide/section4.7.html or here http://www.intorobotics.com/webots-simulation-tutorials-and-resources/